# How to make an on/off switch for a function in a python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have this python program for CSGO hacks that has esp, aimbot, wallhacks and more!
Lets take the triggerbot code for example...

```
#imports
import pymem
from pymem import process
import os
import sys
import time
import win32
from win32 import win32api
import win32process
import keyboard
import threading
from threading import Thread
import offsets
from offsets import *

def trigger():
    while True:
        localplayer = pm.read_int(client + dwLocalPlayer)
        crosshairid = pm.read_int(localplayer + m_iCrosshairId)
        getteam = pm.read_int(client + dwEntityList + (crosshairid - 1)*0x10)
        localteam = pm.read_int(localplayer + m_iTeamNum)
        crosshairteam = pm.read_int(getteam + m_iTeamNum)

        if crosshairid>0 and crosshairid<32 and localteam != crosshairteam:
            pm.write_int(client + dwForceAttack, 6)
```

Now I want to be able to give the user an option to turn it on and off via tkinter switch, but I am not able to figure out on how to make it turn off completely once it is turned on.

I have tried somethings which I don't want to as they were stupid and also I searched on google couldn't find much.

Please help!

Comment: Please share what you tried so far.

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle Honestly not much, but I have put in max effort and thought of ideas but I am unable to think of anything! I even asked in the python server on discord, but no one was able to help

Comment: Wont this `while` loop freeze the GUI? You can use `root.after()` and `root.after_cancel()` to stop the function completely. Do you want a demo answer with it?

Comment: @CoolCloud I'm so dumb I've been trying to get it to work with the while for long now and it keeps freezing! You have no freaking idea how much I'd appreciate it if you could give me an example with root.after() and root.after_cancel()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def run():
    global rep
    if var.get() == 1:
        print('Hey')
        rep = root.after(1000,run) #run the function every 2 second, if checked.
    else:
        root.after_cancel(rep) #cancel if the checkbutton is unchecked.

def step():
    print('This is being printed in between the other loop')

var = IntVar()
b1 = Checkbutton(root,text='Loop',command=run,variable=var)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(root,text='Seperate function',command=step)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**`after()` method takes two arguments mainly:**

- `ms` - time to be run the function
- `func` - the function to run after the given ms is finished.
- `after_cancel()` method takes the variable name of after() only.

Perhaps also keep in mind, you can use `root.update()` and `root.update_idletasks()` with `while` loops, but its not efficient either.

Hope this helped you understand better, do let me know if any doubts or errors.

Cheers

Comment: Damn thanks for the quick response, however, I'm using checkboxes where when it is checked the function runs and when it isnt the function doesnt... Got any idea for that?

Comment: @SDG8 hmmmm, let me see, please wait.

Comment: I really immensely appreciate that you're helping me for starters, so please take the time you need 

Comment: There may be one tiny issue, the code you gave me works only for 1 function, but in my case I have a couple of functions, so for example when I turn on esp, when i turn on the other things the other things dont work

Comment: @SDG8 Example? Maybe you have to update your Q. I recommend asking a new Q

Comment: Uhmm I was going to make a new question but horrible at framing lmao
Anyways here's an example
In python you cant run multiple functions at once and the case that i followed, i can only follow one function at a time, so no matter how many of the boxes i check, it wont matter! For example i turn on esp, it works. After that i turn on aimbot, the aimbot wont work as one function the esp is on already

Comment: @SDG8 hmmmmmmm, you could use `threading`, like whats wrong with `after()` it also allows this right?

Comment: I thought of threading when I tried it, it didnt work? btw you have discord?

Comment: @SDG8 not really, its better to ask a new Q